# How do you change content of page when the link is inside of the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Sorry in advance if I seem confused, it's because I am.

So from my App.js file which is like the main file where I call all my components and query my DB, which is then called by the index.js file.

this is my render method.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="site" >
            {
                !!!this.state.done ? (
                    <LoadingSVG />
                ) : (
                        <div className="page">
                            <div className="header-wrapper">
                                <Header data={this.state.dataHeader} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="project-list-wrapper">
                                <ProjectList data={this.state.dataProjects} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
            }
        </div >
    )
}
```

Inside the Projectlist component I loop through every items and create a project.

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="project-list module">

            <div className="sectionTitle">Project I've worked on</div>

            {this.props.data.map((res, i) => (
                <div className="project-wrapper">
                    <div className="inner-ctn">
                        <div className="header">
                            <div className="number">0{res.id + 1}</div>
                            <div className="name">{res.nomProjet}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="item-ctn">
                            <div className="categ">{res.categProjet}</div>
                            <div className="roles">{res.roles}</div>
                            <div className="date">{res.date}</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

What I want to do is with the use of transition-groups, render another component.. let's call it Project-1. Project 1 would refresh my App.js content so that the new component would render. But I can't do that since App.js is parent to ProjectList. I also want to keep a well structure project so I don't want to put everything in a single file..

I tried reading the documentation and basically every article about how to do this, I can't seem to wrap my mind around how this should work. This should be easy stuff, yet it's weirdly complicated to have a transition or even a link between two pages..

Comment: seems like you want to pass a prop to the child component that does something to the state of the parent component?

Comment: Basically, but is that even possible and two I would want to change  the Header component data so that it's the projects data

Comment: Yes, you can create a function (or method) on the parent component and pass that to a child component.